# Trouble proving properties of the density matrix

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, density-operator, linear-algebra

So let's say you've got a Hilbert space that's $n$-dimensional with some vector $\phi$, such that $\langle \phi | \phi \rangle = 1$; let $|\phi \rangle \langle \phi | = \rho$. Also say we've got some Hermitian operator $\hat{T}$ that denotes some observable $T$. I'm trying to show 3 things.

First off, I want to prove that $\langle T \rangle$, the average (expected) value observation  equals $\mathrm{Tr}(\rho T)$. I am very unsure as to how to do this, and have been trying to use the eigenbasis obtained from $T$ to express $\phi$, but am having a lot of difficulty simplifying and could use some guidance.

Secondly, I'm trying to show that $\mathrm{Tr}(\rho) = 1$. This seems like it has to do with the eigenvalues of $\rho$ but I seem to be missing some insight.

Finally, I want to prove that the adjoint of $\rho$ equals $\rho$; in other words that $\rho$ itself is a hermitian operator. This too I'm a little confused about; I'm trying to define and use a gram matrix for the inner product definition of the adjoint, with little success.

Would appreciate any help anyone could provide. Thanks!

Comment: $\langle T\rangle  = \mathrm{Tr} \rho\, T$ is a definition?!

Answer (score 1):

Let $\mathcal{H}$ be a finite-dimensional Hilbert space of dimension $n$. The trace of an operator $T$ on $\mathcal{H}$ is defined as
$$\mathrm{Tr}(T) := \sum_{k=1}^n \langle e_k | T |e_k\rangle,$$
where $\{e_k\}_{k=1}^n$ is an orthonormal basis of $\mathcal{H}$. A theorem from linear algebra ensures that the sum on the r.h.s. of this equation is independent of the chosen basis. Using this definition, your questions should be easy to answer:

1. Expectation value of $T$ in the state $\phi$ with $\rho= |\phi\rangle\langle\phi |$:
   $$\mathrm{Tr}(\rho T) = \mathrm{Tr}(|\phi \rangle\langle\phi | T) = \sum_{k=1}^n \langle e_k | \phi \rangle \langle\phi | T |e_k\rangle = \langle \phi | T | \sum_{k=1}^n \langle e_k | \phi \rangle e_k \rangle = \langle \phi| T |\phi\rangle = \langle T \rangle_\phi.$$ I used Parseval's indentity: $\phi = \sum_{k=1}^n \langle e_k | \phi \rangle e_k$.
2. The trace of $\rho$:
   $$\mathrm{Tr}(\rho) = \sum_{k=1}^{n} \langle e_k| \phi\rangle \langle \phi|e_k\rangle = \sum_{k=1}^n |\langle e_k|\phi\rangle|^2 = \|\phi\|^2.$$
   If $|\phi\rangle$ is normalised, then $\| \phi\|^2 = \langle \phi | \phi \rangle = 1$.
3. For hermiticity, we need to show that $\langle \psi | \rho \varphi \rangle = \langle \rho \psi |\varphi \rangle$ for all $\psi,\varphi \in \mathcal{H}$:
   $$ \langle \psi | \rho \varphi \rangle = \langle \psi | \phi \rangle \langle \phi | \varphi \rangle = \langle \phi \langle \phi | \psi \rangle | \varphi \rangle = \langle \rho \psi | \varphi\rangle.$$
   In the second step, I employed that the scalar product is anti-linear in the first component.

As a remark, let me mention that if $\mathcal{H}$ is infinite-dimensional (usually the case in quantum mechanics), then the trace of an arbitrary operator $T$ is not necessarily defined because the sum $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \langle e_k|T|e_k\rangle$ may not converge (see [trace-class operators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_class)).

Answer (score 0):

If $\rho=|\phi\rangle\langle\phi|$, then $tr\{\rho\}=\langle\phi|\phi\rangle=1$. So that part is easy.

Moreover, $|\phi\rangle^{\dagger}=\langle\phi|$ and visa versa. So the Hermitian property of $\rho$ is also easy to show.

The only thing is to compute the expectation value of the operator. For that you need to expand $\rho$ in terms of the eigenbasis of $T$. The expectation values will then be expressed in terms of the expansion coefficients.

Answer (score -1):

Adding to the other answer, if you take it as known that
$$ \langle T \rangle = \langle \psi | T | \psi \rangle, $$
then you can easily rewrite this as
$$ \mathrm{Tr}(\langle \psi | T | \psi \rangle) = \mathrm{Tr}(| \psi \rangle \langle \psi | T) = \mathrm{Tr}(\rho T)$$ by cyclicity of trace (since $x = \mathrm{Tr}(x)$ when $x$ is just a number). Then in particular $1 = \langle 1 \rangle = \mathrm{Tr}(\rho)$.

Comment: Note that, for $x\in \mathbb{C}$, $\mathrm{Tr}(x) = x\mathrm{Tr}(1) = nx$.

Comment: @Janik Yes. Here I view $x = \langle \psi | T | \psi \rangle$ as an operator $\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$, ie a $1 \times 1$ matrix, so $n = 1$. (In contrast, $| \psi \rangle \langle \psi | T$ is an operator from the Hilbert space to itself.)